# Difference between dot (.) pronoun and .data pronoun

Tags: r, rlang

While building my first R package I ran `devtools::check()` which resulted the following note: `no visible binding for global variable ‘.’`

In order to fix that I tried to be more explicit and changed any instance of `.` to `rlang::.data`. While it did solved the `devtools` note, it made the functions using it to provide wrong output. Here's an example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rlang)

# Creating df with missing values
iris_w_na <- head(iris)
iris_w_na[iris_w_na == 0.2] <- NA

### Replace missing values using .
# This works
iris_w_na %>% replace(is.na(.), -99)

# This doesn't
iris_w_na %>% replace(is.na(rlang::.data), -99)

# This won't work either
na_indexes <- iris_w_na %>% is.na(rlang::.data)

# But this will work
na_indexes <- iris_w_na %>% is.na(.)
iris_w_na %>% replace(na_indexes, -99)
```

Ultimately I went back to use `.` and solved the `devtools` note by putting `utils::globalVariables(".")` in the package documentation.

However I'm still interested to know what are the differences between `.` and `.data` and why they behave differently in the above-mentioned example.

Comment: According to `?'.data'` `It makes it easy to refer to column names stored as strings. If var contains the column "height", the pronoun will subset that column:` and the example given is within the `summarise` etc to extract the column.  Here you are trying to use it on the whole data

Comment: I was under the impression that if you can refer a specific column using `.data[["height"]]` just like a normal data frame, you can also refer to the entire data frame by just using `.data` but this doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: As I mentioned you are using `.data` outside the framework of tidyverse functions which may not work unless you provide some wrapper `as_wrapper` or so, `head(iris) %>% .data
Error in .data(.) : could not find function ".data"`  Also, even if you use within `mutate/summarise` `head(iris) %>% mutate(col = .data)
Error: Must subset the data pronoun with a string
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace#
`head(iris) %>% mutate(col = .data$Species)` - works